# Find id by matching the values

Tags: sql, relational-division

I have two tables, but IMO only the first is necessary for this question.

```
conversation_id  user 
conv1        randomuser
conv1        admin    
conv2        derp   
conv3        derp   
conv3        admin  
conv3        herp   
conv4        derp   
conv4        admin
```

Now I want to select the conversation_id by `derp` and `admin`. The conversation_id should then be `conv4`.

I have tried many options and the "best" working I found is:

```
SELECT chat_och_users_in_conversation.conversation_id AS conv_id FROM     
chat_och_users_in_conversation  
WHERE USER IN ('derp', 'admin')
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM chat_och_users_in_conversation 
        WHERE conversation_id = conv_id ) = 2
```

The conv_id which is returned are `conv1` and `conv4`. I think I understand why this is returned: the `IN` works like an `OR` in matching rows.

Note that this should work on many different database types, so not only MySQL.

Comment: I don't think so. This would result in matching one column with 2 values.

Comment: Please clarify: why would conv3 not be returned as well? Because it contains 'herp'?

Comment: Yes indeed. I'm searching the id of the conversation with exactly those users in it. It can't contains more or less users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only few values you can use `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.conversation_id AS conv_id 
FROM   chat_och_users_in_conversation    c1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM chat_och_users_in_conversation  c2
    WHERE c1.conversation_id = c2.conversation_id
    AND   c2.user = 'derp'
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM chat_och_users_in_conversation  c2
    WHERE c1.conversation_id = c2.conversation_id
    AND   c2.user = 'admin'
)
AND NOT EXISTS
( 
    SELECT 1 FROM chat_och_users_in_conversation  c2
    WHERE c1.conversation_id = c2.conversation_id
    AND   c2.user NOT IN ('derp', 'admin')
)
```

It's verbose but simple(just copy-paste) and comprehensible. It can also be changed or extended easily.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ad51/4/0)</kbd>

Comment: For large conversations (with many users) this isn't a good option. It also doesn't work.

Comment: @LEDfan: i've added a sql-fiddle to demonstrate that it works (I've mistakenly selected `user` instead of `derp`). It all depends on your indexes. But it should be one of the most efficient approaches even on MySql(for sure on SQL-Server). I prefer it because you can modify it easily if  the rule changes.

Comment: @LEDfan: do you want only conv4 because it doesn't contain any other  user? I have edited my answer again to take that into account. You need also a `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want all value:

```
SELECT conversation_id AS conv_id 
FROM chat_och_users_in_conversation  
WHERE USER IN ('derp', 'admin')
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT USER) = 2
```

Or only the last one?

```
SELECT MAX(conversation_id) AS conv_id 
FROM chat_och_users_in_conversation  
WHERE USER IN ('derp', 'admin')
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT USER) = 2
```

Comment: Mmm. I tried your changes before but it just returns `conv3` and `conv4`

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted. I must have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.conversation_id  
from chat_och_users_in_conversation  a1 JOIN chat_och_users_in_conversation  a2 on a1.conversation_id  = a2.conversation_id  
WHERE a1.user <> a2.user and a1.User in ('derp') and a2.user in ('admin')
```

If you want to exclude conversations with someone other than admin and derp

```
with cte as(
SELECT DISTINCT a1.conversation_id  cid
from chat_och_users_in_conversation  a1 
JOIN chat_och_users_in_conversation  a2 on a1.conversation_id  = a2.conversation_id  
WHERE a1.[user] <> a2.[user] and a1.[User] in ('derp') and a2.[user] in ('admin')
)
select * from cte where cid not in (select a3.conversation_id from chat_och_users_in_conversation a3 where a3.[user] 
                                       NOT IN ('derp','admin'))
```